# How to highlight unique cell in UI Grid using cellClass function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

My requirement is that I am suppose to be highlighting specific cell by its row number and column number. But in given plunked when I scroll the grid other cell also getting highlighted. Looks like I have not understood UI grid cellClass method. Can anyone enlighten me? if my understanding is incorrect how will I achieve this functionality where only specific cell will be highlighted (ref to row number and column number.)

below is my core part of code and plunker.

```
var uniqueCellInfoArr = [{"row":2,"col":1},{"row":4,"col":1} ]
cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) 
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < uniqueCellInfoArr.length; i++)
          {
            if ( uniqueCellInfoArr[i].row == rowRenderIndex &&  uniqueCellInfoArr[i].col == colRenderIndex)
            {
              return "red"
            }
          }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5xQoKiKIL8vY8EeLsJG5?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i could solve this. I modified plunker with my solution.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQu94rC5jxzYDZQQa5P4?p=preview

below property currentTopRow saved me.

```
rowRenderIndex = rowRenderIndex+grid.renderContainers.body.currentTopRow;
```

Every time rowRenderIndex was being reset while it was being scrolled. Adding this variable helped me to come out with fix location number hence only i could achieve specific cell being highlighted with row and col details.

Answer (score 2):

The rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex is the index of the cell which are rendered in the table. When you scroll down, the cell are render again, so the indexes are rested.

A better solution is to highlight the cell based on it value, you can do it like this

```
var uniqueCellInfoArr = ['Velity','Suretech'];

cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) 
    {
      var cellValue = grid.getCellValue(row, col);
      if(uniqueCellInfoArr.indexOf(cellValue) > -1) return 'red';
    }
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g2QoWcWdP5FYKOwMOUm8?p=preview

Comment: Due to some reason i can not go by value because. This is just a sample here. In my working code similarly i have numbers. Many numbers are repeating.

Comment: Can you provide some example of these numbers?

Comment: For example in this same example. if "Vality" and "Suretech" get repeated(I mean duplicate) in the grid will be highlighted too. but i want to highlight specific instance referring (rowNo and Col number not the value of the cell). I was thinking rowRenderIndex and colRenderIndex will give me fix cell reference but it looks like it giving me relative reference(May be specific to viewport)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is over a year old, but it is misleading. The suggested answer is to just slap `!important` onto the field class and this really isn't necessary. The important rule should only be used when absolutely needed. A work around is to just raise the CSS specificity with the following to override any defaults:

```
.grid .ui-grid-row .red { color: red;  background-color: yellow; }
.grid .ui-grid-row .blue { color: blue;  }
```

See: [Dynamic Cells Styling in ui-grid](http://brianhann.com/customize-ui-grid-with-dynamic-cell-classes/)